# style tags in html partials

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-ui-router

Is it beneficial to include style and script tags in my html partials? I feel like it makes more sense but I'm not 100% sure. My definition of beneficial would be:

- It scales well in terms of maintenance and modifications.
- There is little to no performance penalty.
- The code is easier to understand.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about

```
<html>

    <style>
        /*Application wide styling*/
        body{
            height:1000px;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>

    <body>

        <!-- Include homepage partial -->

    </body>
</html>


<!-- homepage partial -->

<style>
        .subcontent_wrapper{
            height:40px;
        }
</style>
<div class="main_content">
    <div class="subcontent_wrapper">
        <!-- include subcontent1 partial -->
    </div>
    <div class="subcontent_wrapper">
        <!-- include subcontent2 partial -->
    </div>
</div>

<!-- subcontent1 -->
<style>
    #subcontent1{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
</style>
<div id="subcontent1" class="subcontent">
    <p>Hello,</p>
</div>


<!-- subcontent2 -->
<style>
    #subcontent2{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
</style>
<div id="subcontent2" class="subcontent">
    <p>World!</p>
</div>
```

Does this have any pros/cons over the normal way, which is to just include all of the css separately?

edit: by html partial, I mean any html which is dynamically inserted into the document. It is commonly done to break up a page into "wrappers" and insert other html files into them. When I say include html partial, the html partial that I refer to is inserted into that area of the document.

Comment: what is html partial?

Comment: I answered your question in my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a little bit close to opinion, but I would say **no** to including style tags (they shouldn't really be in HTML anywhere. That's what CSS is for!) in HTML partials.

As for script tags, add them wherever you need to; sometimes JavaScript needs to be placed in specific locations in an HTML document, so without altering your code to allow it to run from within the `<head>` element, you'll have to.

Answer (score 0):

Including `<style></style>` inside your HTML code is a very bad practice since it greatly handicaps the maintainability of your code.

I don't know where did you get your assumptions but let's discuss those a little:

> It scales well in terms of maintenance and modifications.

This is absolutely false.
Your app will probably reach more than a couple of pages, and when this will happen, you will find yourself with tens (or hundreds?) of little `<style>` snippets here and there.

Good luck then when you decide you want that font a little bigger...

> There is little to no performance penalty.

This is also not true.
It may not be noticeable, at first, but when your app will grow, you will have a lot of redundant CSS dispersed everywhere in your code.

Which of course is extra bits of information that needs to be downloaded.

> The code is easier to understand.

Today, maybe.
Look at the code a month from now, and you will curse yourself trying to find your snippet between tens (or hundreds) of other almost identical snippets...

---

Also, as a side note, you shouldn't include an `<html>` tag in a partial.

**Edit: I almost forgot about the scripts**
Since you tagged your question as `angular-ui-router` I suppose you're using `AngularJS`.
In that case, it makes no sens **at all** to have script tags that litters you HTML.

Comment: I was not making assumptions, I asked if it would be beneficial and I explained my definition of beneficial. Thank you for your thorough answer!

Comment: Oh oops, I misread that part. Anyway, my thorough answer led to some downvote from an unknown (an unexplained) benefactor... cool!